# Where upstreams could be located in openresty server?

Tags: nginx, openresty

I got a task to tweak `nginx.conf` in openresty server to add one more location and upstream but I just cant find where they are.

I can see from `/var/log/openresty/access.log` that traffic is going smoothly to our backends but there are no locations in `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`

`grep "upstream" /usr/local/openresty/*` and `grep "location" /usr/local/openresty/*` gives me nothing useful

Answer (score 0):

Alright.

At the bottom of `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` there is an `include` statement that I missed:

```
include ../sites/*;
```

The config I was looking for is there